# Одновременный запуск алгоритма в потоках

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Разбираю задачи на многопоточность с гонкой за ресурсами. Какие есть методы одновременного старта нескольких потоков? Знаю что можно сделать через atomic. Правильно ли я использую atomic_bool и как можно сделать по другому?

```
std::atomic_bool ready{ false };
struct B {  
    void start(){
        while (!ready);
        // здесь алгоритм 
    };
};
int main() {
    B b1, b2;

    std::thread thread1(&B::start,b1);
    std::thread thread1(&B::start, b2);

    ready = true;
    b1.join();
    b2.join();
return 0;    };
```

Comment: Тут наверно лучше подойдет (condition_variable::notify_all)[https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all), хотя и Ваш вариант должен работать. Но вот только запустить потоки "одновременно" не получится. Все равно будет какой то интервал.

Comment: Обычно как раз наоборот, предполагается, что потоки стартуют с непредсказуемой неодновременностью. Если это не система реального времени, то никакой возможности добиться одновременного старта нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В многопоточных программах сихронизация выполняется **без** бесконечных циклов. В начале был вариант использовать функции подачи сигналов другим спящим процессам, например `condition.totify_all();`. Но возникали неприятности из-за полного зависания программы, если подали сигнал, а клиент ещё не успел дать команду `.wait()`. Сигнал отправился **только** тем процессам, что ожидали его. И пришлось ещё сначала проверять флаг, задача готова или нет.

В Си++ позже дописали удобные инструменты именно для *одноразового* момента синхронизации потоков. Это `promise` и `future`. `promise` посылает сигнал, что задача выполнена, а `future` *только* если задача ещё не была выполнена, ожидает сигнал.

---

```
# include <atomic>
# include <future>
# include <thread>
# include <unistd.h>
std::promise<void> pready;
auto fready = pready.get_future();
//std::atomic_flag ready{ false };
struct B {  
    void start(){
        fready.wait();
        //while (!ready);
        // здесь алгоритм 
    };
};
int main() {
    B b1, b2;

    std::thread thread1(&B::start,b1);
    std::thread thread2(&B::start, b2);

    sleep(1);

    //ready = true;
    pready.set_value();

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    return 0;    }
```

Answer (score 1):

В C++20 для этого есть `std::latch` и `std::barrier`. Для однократной синхронизации лучше `std::latch`.

Ожидание `while (!ready);` плохо тем, что напрасно рсходуются ресурсы процессора, которые могли бы служить потоку, выполняющему более полезную работу. В С++20 есть `std::atomic::wait` для ожидания на атомарной переменной. Но всё равно просто `ready = true;` имеет тот недостаток, что потоки могут к этому моменту не дойти до точки ожидания.

До C++20 -- да, можно сделать на condition variable, но решение будет громоздким (и слегка менее эффективным). Или обратиться к библиотекам (в boost есть barrier и latch) или к примитивам ОС (futex в linux, Event Object в Windows)

Гарантированной одновременности достичь невозможно, но задача может стоять чтобы каждый поток выполнил некую инициализацию перед выполнением дальнейшего кода.

Comment: Это конечно, верно, но справедливости ради надо заметить, что на не загруженной системе, когда все потоки исполняются (не попадают в список ожидающих), одновременность начала работы (в большинстве случаев) будет выше при активном ожидании на `ready`